# Listview with Checkbox not Multiple Choice

Tags: android, android-listview

I have my ListView now and I want to insert a checkBox on its side and I don't want to use the MultipleChoice item. Can Someone tell me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this to make a single choice list view:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                arrayList);

listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What i mean is, a Checkbox that is not from the listView, what i want is, a android widget checkbox..

Comment: You can create custom layout for the rows in the list view. create another xml file and design it the way u want the rows in the list to look like. Then use that layout in the list view by this: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    R.layout.row_layout, arrayList);